# How create authentication with Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I want to change my client code to use Prediction 1.6 but it uses the new Google Apis 1.5.X and i cant create the required authenticator.

An example to create an authenticator for Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer with Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2?

I was able to create this authenticator with previous Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2 but it doesnt works anymore with APis 1.5.X

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate more and the problem?

1. Why can't you create the required authenticator? What is the exact problem?
2. You have many code samples on how to work with OAuth2 flows in our samples repository . Take a look in this sample - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg%2FTasks.SimpleOAuth2. If you can run this sample, you can use part of its code, and copy it to your required solution.

Please provide more details, exceptions, runtime errors or whatever you are dealing with so we will be able to help you!

Comment: Ok, based on that example i founded that it uses a nuget package named "Google APIs OAuth2 Client Library" but i downloaded a nugget package named "Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2 Client Library". Similar names but not the same.
I was not able to find the correct one on nugget page. If you perform a search on that package it wont show up. I had to use Visual Studio Nugget searcher and activate "show prerealese packages"

Comment: That link doesn't lead to samples. It leads to the root repository. Does that mean that the samples don't exit anymore, or is it somewhere else now?

Comment: I also don't see any examples :\

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on that example i founded that it uses a nuget package named "Google APIs OAuth2 Client Library" but i downloaded a nugget package named "Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2 Client Library". Similar names but not the same. I was not able to find the correct one on nugget page. If you perform a search on that package it wont show up. I had to use Visual Studio Nugget searcher and activate "show prerealese packages" to install it

Comment: You are right, our library is still beta. So if you want to install it you should enable prerelease packages as well. And regarding the names, I know it's tricky. We will improve it in the next release!

Answer (score 0):

Are these the droids you're looking for?

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Authentication/1.5.0-beta

Go to NuGet, run the search for 'Google APIs OAuth2 Client Library', then, after the 0 results have loaded, click on the 'Stable only' drop down and select 'Include Prerelease' and it'll re-run the search and you should see it at the top of the list.

I know this should've been a comment but I don't seem to be able to do them, yet.